# Chrome loading facebook.com causing hard disk keeps on spinning

Tags: facebook

Big spinning noise from hard disk when browsing facebook.com, not other websites.
I know facebook sucks, but need to use their site for a while.

This is a i7-8700T PC, 24 GB memory, ubuntu 22.04. That's all i cared in the past, not familiar with any other specifications. Mostly just doing web browsing.

Any suggestions to solve this problem ?

More info:

1. i turned on top command after reboot, just open chrome, 5 tabs for 5 different sites, all good so far.
2. open facebook market place in a new tab, CPU could jump to 200%, memory is ok.
3. close the facebook tab, CPU goes down back to 10%.

Comment: Are you sure it's your HDD that's making the noise? Your HDD should only be used minimally on websites unless you are actively downloading/uploading something in the background. I find it more likely that your CPU cooler or desktop/laptop fans are spinning faster. If that is the case, then you could try changing your fan curves using fan control software. Often that can fix the issue for CPU fans, desktop/laptop fans, and GPU fans if you change the right settings. Best of luck.